# Copy TEMPFILE in python

Tags: python

Can you please help me how to copy or execute any action against the tempfile in python

Code:

```
f = tempfile.TemporaryFile()  
f.write(b"Testing code") 
f.seek(0)
command = "copy " + '"' + f.name + '"' + ' "' + "./" + '"'
os.system(command)
```

Error: The process cannot access the file became it is being used by another process.

If i use the close(), it delete the tempfile.

How to use the file like copy or execute before it will delete

Execute the action against the temp file

Answer (score 0):

'TemporaryFile' automatically cleans up the file when it's closed, you can use 'NamedTemporaryFile' instead

```
import tempfile
import shutil
import os

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as f:
    f.write(b"Testing code")
    f.seek(0)
    # Your action here, e.g., copying the file
    shutil.copy(f.name, "./")
```

Comment: You probably ought to delete the temporary file after the copy. Also, this probably won't work on Windows because the temporary file is open when you try to make the copy

Answer (score 0):

You're sort of creating your own paradox.  You want a temporary file, which by definition deletes when you close it, but then you don't want it to actually delete when you close it.

A simple solution would be to create a temporary directory, and then create your own file within the temporary directory.

```
with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as d:
    filename = os.path.join(d, "mystuff.txt")
    print(filename)
    with open(filename, "w") as f:
        f.write("Testing code")
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a named temporary file. Do not delete on close. Make a note of the temporary filename before closing (implicitly with context manager). Write to the file. Rename the temporary file.

```
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
from os.path import basename
from os import rename
   
with NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as f:
    f.write(b"Testing code")
    name = f.name

base = basename(name)
print(f"Renaming temporary file to {base}")
rename(name, base)
```